# Can PostgreSQL bulk update cause issue in Logical replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, aws-aurora

I use AWS Aurora PostgreSQL. PS version:13(updated the question)

We use Logical slots(wal2json) to replicate to the data warehouse. Recently one of the Bulk updates queries updated 40 million rows.

After that, my cluster's IOPS went too high and the queue depth went to 80. All the operations got blocked.

Then we removed the replication slots, and everything back to normal. I know the bulk update should have been done in batches. Just trying to understand if is this a bottleneck in logical replication. how do we handle such use cases in the future? Can pgoutput makes sense here?

Comment: That sounds more like a limit that AWS Aurora imposes, not a problem caused by Postgres

Comment: Maybe you had bad plans due to the stats being out of date, and then autovacuum finished around the same time you dropped the slot.  Aurora offers monitoring tools beyond just looking at IOPS, you should use them to see what is going on.

Comment: v10 is at EOL.  Many improvements have been made to logical replication since then including decoding of large transactions, although I don't know how much wal2json is effected by those changes.  What version of wal2json is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, its due to aurora's storage structure. It has some limitations.

The hint is - Aurora's commit process in the disk is different from EC2 EBS. ( I can't disclose some of the internal things in aurora)